# View used by multiple methods - where should I put my findViewById()?

Tags: android

I'm using a particular TextView: `TextView txtStatusView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);` in several methods in my view's .java file.  In each method I'm using the above line of code to find and initialize the same txtStatus view.   Should I instead be putting this once at the top of the class (my thought: to prevent wasting time or power finding the view every time), or is it better that I have this line for each method that uses the view?

Comment: If I am understand you correctly you can try [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/textview/android-textview-example/)

Comment: Store it in a filed of your `Activity` and initialize the field in the `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable globally and define it inside your onCreate()

Declare like:

```
TextView txtStatusView;
```

Inside onCreate():

```
txtStatusView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
```

Comment: If you do it inside onCreate(),then you don't have to use it inside same class over and over again

Comment: So if I put it in the onCreate() will I be able to access it in other methods the same way?  
Edit: Got it (saw previous comment that answered this)!

Comment: Yes. You just have to use  `txtStatusView .setText("Your data to be displayed");` wherever you want to set text to `Textview`. Use it accordingly.